# Ideas for what to do with timestamp only dataset, for a machine learning project

Tags: datetime, machine-learning, timestamp, project

I am writing a machine learning project (I am quite new to this) and now I have gotten a little stuck as to what to do next.

I have 2, somewhat small datasets, one of them has timestamps for when the output has happened, the other one is the same but has the input timestamps, they are in a format: year/month/day/hour/minute/second.

I have tried to do quite a bit of feature engineering and split these columns, as well as looked into the difference between the nearest inputs, and nearest outputs to see understand the time lags better as well as try to see the downtime. I have done a lot of visualizations to see where I can go from here and now I am quite stuck. There isn't any obvious patterns that I can see.

I do not need to do time series forecasting, and am now trying to do anomaly detection on what I have.

- My issue is that I have no idea what I should do with this next, maybe you have some advice on what algorithms I can apply?
- I am also stuck to see whether I am able to connect the input to its output timestamp, is there any obvious ways that are usually applied to do that?
- I mainly want to see patterns, and deviations in the data, I have tried looking at scrap data that is generated. I do not really know what are the good models/experiments to apply and try out in my case.
- is there any data mining methods you could advise me to use?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are on the right track!

Here are some ideas to consider:

- Is there a trend by day of week? Are weekends peak or not?
- Does the hour of the day combined with day of week make a difference?
- Have you looked at volume in combination with other variables? A spike in traffic on Wednesday night at 2am could be a red flag.

Basically I'd try to code in seasonality, hour, day of week, month, year,  etc. into your data.

Link: [How to use machine learning for anomaly detection and condition monitoring](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-machine-learning-for-anomaly-detection-and-condition-monitoring-6742f82900d7);
[Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)